# What is the result of executing a PDO statement containing two SELECT queries?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

What is the result of executing a statement in PDO if it contains two select queries? Consider this table:

```
A    B
------
a    1
b    2
c    3
d    4
e    5
f    6
```

and this PDO query:

```
$sql = $pdo->prepare("
    SELECT A FROM Table WHERE B > 3;
    SELECT A FROM Table WHERE B < 3;
");
$sql->execute();
```

What will `$sql->fetchAll()` return?

Comment: -1 Those are really really silly "for why you didnt try it".  You had time to create this question but you had no time to click a button to test this?  That is not good.  You also state can get some reputation, anyone trying to get reputation is really desperate, this site is not about points its about HELP.

Comment: @JonH, I had no time to start a localhost server, create a MYSQL table for testing purpose, populate it with stupid datas, write a PHP file and test it myself. Also what is really wrong with this question? Couldn't it be usefull to someone else?

Comment: @Charlie Pigarelli - if someone really needed help with something like this they would post it.  But don't post stuff on stackoverflow to help people gain rep points.  The people on this site who really care to help don't care about points, they care about technology, innovation, and knowledge.  So they are willing to help irregardless of how many points they earn.  Your reasons for not wanting to test were flat out silly.

Comment: 4 Votes to close? Seriously "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form." Is it true?

Comment: @George, and a fall on top of home plate!

Comment: @Charlie Pigarelli - Possibly.

Comment: @JonH, I'd like to add a feature to one of my project and i was trying to figure out how and i thought about this question that will depends on how I add this feature. And I had no time for it. ALSO someone could gain legit reputations points ALSO it could be usefull to someone.

Comment: @Charlie Pigarelli - In the future don't post the reasons why, just ask the question.

Comment: @JonH, this is just stupid. Just because I put "2) You can get some reputations" in the question it is closed for "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.". It's stupid and sad, really. Anyway I got my answer from the one who posted it and then delete it.

Comment: @Charlie Pigarelli - If you got your answer then move on stop whining.

Comment: @JonH et al: I agree that the question as it stood was unfortunately worded, but I disagree that the core of it wasn't a real question. I've edited the question and voted to reopen.

Comment: Vote to reopen. Question might be way off, but it's certainly a question. -- Btw, it could very well depend on the database if this works. In any case the `UNION ALL` answer is only one valid reply.

Comment: I'll vote to reopen because its better to agree then disagree and arguing never works; its also now correctly worded. My vote is also for UNION ALL if you want to combine the results of both queries.

Comment: @Charlie Pigarelli - Question was voted to reopen, I removed my -1 for it.

Comment: Never seen a question getting down voted 4 times and closed, be reopened and reach +3... Without any edits to the original question.

Comment: Still it remain selfish question out of laziness. You're leeching on community and wasting other people time to save yours. It's a shame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine queries using `UNION ALL`

Like so:

```
SELECT A FROM Table WHERE B > 3;     
UNION ALL
SELECT A FROM Table WHERE B < 3;
```

First select statement returns the records d,e,f for A.
Second statement returns a,b for A.
The result is combined into one single return

`d,e,f,a,b`

Now can I have my points ;) (just kidding)

Comment: @All edited to return A rather then B :) - my bad...and boy do I need caffeine.

Answer (score 4):

You are executing a statement with 2 `SELECT` queries, `$sql->fetch()` will return the results from the 1st statement only.